# Using Django ORM to aggregate attribute value across filtered queryset

Tags: django

A django queryset contains user uploaded photos and their corresponding upvotes (from viewers).

I need to run a query which returns all the votes added together. Is there any way to use the ORM to return the aggregate votes? I'm assuming it would be faster than how I'm currently doing it (performance matters for me here).

---

Currently I'm trying the following:

```
yesterday = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours = 24)
photos = Photo.objects.filter(upload_time__gte=yesterday)
cumulative_votes = 0
for photo in photos:
    cumulative_votes += photo.total_votes
```

Comment: How about `Photo.objects.filter(upload_time__gte=yesterday).aggregate(Count("total_votes"))`?

Comment: showing what the model actually looks like will help a lot. is total_votes an attribute or a property?

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi: stuck somewhere else, I'll mark yours soon after checking both answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a one-liner:

```
total_vote_sum = Photo.objects.filter(filter_stuff).aggregate(Sum("total_votes"))["total_votes__sum"]
```

quote from:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset

*aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked, returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. The name is automatically generated from the name of the field and the aggregate function.*

so `queryset.aggregate(Sum('field'))` will return a dictionary like:
`{"field__sum": 'result'}`

with this in mind, we can get our desired result directly like so:

```
result = queryset.aggregate(Sum('field'))['field__sum']
```

Comment: Cool. Quick explanation? It's the first time I'm seeing this pattern.

Comment: I didn't know it returned a dictionary object. Cool way to reduce everything to one line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Sum,or Count functions of Django db,
Like this :

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
yesterday = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours = 24)

photos = Photo.objects.filter(upload_time__gte=yesterday).aggregate(total_votes=Count('total_votes'))
photo_sum = photos['total_votes']
```

Or

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
yesterday = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours = 24)

photos = Photo.objects.filter(upload_time__gte=yesterday).aggregate(total_votes=Sum('total_votes'))
photo_sum = photos['total_votes']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this method works on the attribute level.

Comment: if total_votes is an integer, it makes no sense to only count them, he wants the total sum.

Comment: @Brian: yep that's what I need. This just returns the count of objects I think.

Comment: @Brian Update my answer.Please check.

Comment: @HassanBaig photo_sum variable will have the total sum of all the values of total_votes field.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi: in this particular case, `Count` and `Sum` are interchangeable?

Comment: Yeah,I checked it with my code,both are returning same count

Comment: what if the total_votes field has a value of 5 instead of 1 though?

Comment: Yes, that's how my `total_votes` are saved - it's a cumulative counter.

Comment: @Brian aggregate function returns a dict with only 1 key value pair inside it.  And you can check the results in your project,The result is cumulative sum of all the values inside total_votes field of Photo model.

Comment: @HassanBaig I checked the results,For the information you provided,total_votes is a field inside Photo model with integers inside it.My answer counts the total of total_votes field

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi: checking it out.